# Переход в ItemActivity

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, adapter

Как правильно реализовать то, что я хочу. 
У нас есть Список айтэмов, переходить в списке в ItemAcitivty я знаю как. И есть еще активити создания айтэма и как по нажатию кнопки в данной активити, можно переходить к ItemActivity с только что заполненными данными.

Это действие происходит в **onBindViewHolder**

```
itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                eventSelected(itemHolder, item);
            }
        });
```

-

```
public void eventSelected(EventsListItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, EventListItem item) {
    String id = item.event.getId();
    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View) itemViewHolder.mTitleView, "event_title");
        Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create((View) itemViewHolder.mInterestViewColor, "event_interest_bg");
        Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create((View) itemViewHolder.mImageView, "ivent_image");
        Pair<View, String> p4 = Pair.create((View) itemViewHolder.mInterestTitle, "event_interest_name");
        optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, p1, p2, p3, p4);
    }
    if (mSelectItemListener != null) {
        mSelectItemListener.onEventItemSelected(id, optionsCompat);
    }
}
```

А вот слушатели:

```
 public interface SelectEventItemListener {
    void onEventItemSelected(String eventId, ActivityOptionsCompat options);
    void onEventEditSelected(String eventId);
}

public void setOnSelectItemListener(SelectEventItemListener listener) {
    mSelectItemListener = listener;
}
```

Comment: передайте все *только что заполненные данные* через интент.

Comment: @metalurgus как это делается?

Comment: там, где startActivity(), в интент сложите данные(intent.putExtra(...)), а в ItemActivity - getIntent().getExtra();

Comment: @metalurgus у каждого заполняющегося айтэма, свой ID. И в главной активити я перехожу по клику на  айтэм и перехожу нормально. Нельзя ли реализовать переход в АйтэмАктивити с ID?

Comment: ну так а есть ID у *только что заполненных данных*? Если есть, то и переходите по этому ID

Comment: @metalurgus а как по клику на кнопку преходить по ID?

Comment: @metalurgus просто в Адаптере обрабатывать клик легче. Ибо там переход привязан к CardView

Comment: А как вы переходите по ID? Я ж не знаю. Так же само, только ID берите у новосозданной записи.

Comment: @metalurgus добавил выше, как я перехожу к EventActivity.